# Asynchronous Chat Server using Mojolicious

Tags: perl, asynchronous, mojolicious

Hello Ladies and Gentleman! I am currently writing a minimalistic chat server that will somewhat resemble IRC. I am writing it in perl using the Mojolicious, but unfortunately have run into an issue. I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Mojo::IOLoop::Server;

my $server = Mojo::IOLoop::Server->new;

$server->on(accept => sub {
    my ($server, $handle) = @_;
    my $data;

    print $handle "Connected!\n";

    while(1) {
        $handle->recv($data, 4096);

        if($data) {
            print $server "$data";
        }
    }
});

$server->listen(port => $ARGV[0]);
$server->start;
$server->reactor->start unless $server->reactor->is_running;
```

Unfortunately, the print $server "$data"; line does not actually work. It gives off the error:

```
Mojo::Reactor::Poll: I/O watcher failed: Not a GLOB reference at ./server.pl line 20.
```

I have looked through the documentation for Mojolicious, but cannot find how to send the line I get from client A to the rest of the clients connected.

Comment: what mojo version do you use?

Comment: 6.56 Clinking Beer Mugs it looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `$handle` is something like a stream you can write on, `$server` is a `Mojo::IOloop::Server` object, so it's not a surprise you can't write on it like you're trying to do.

Even if I use Mojolicious quite often, I'm not familiar with every possibilities (there are a lot), but here what I would suggest : you need to store a list of all connected clients (in a hash or an array for instance), and when you receive a message, you iterate through that client list, to send the message to all of them.

You also need a way (not hard to do) to delete clients from your clients list when they disconnect.

Also I'm not quite sure about your infinite loop : I wouldn't be surprised if it was blocking the server on the 1st connected client.
It's better to use Mojolicious functions to do so :

```
$serv->on(message => sub { send the message to all clients });
```

And that function would be called every time a message is received.

Here is a good example, using `Mojolicious::Light`, pretty easy to understand I think : https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Writing-websocket-chat-using-Mojolicious-Lite

Comment: Thank you so much! That actually makes a lot of sense. You are also right, the while loop was blocking, but I was going to handle that later. I appreciate the help!